# Status of religious literature composed in regional languages

Tags: scripture, language, sampradaya

Sanskrit is the undisputed liturgical language of Hinduism, & many books dealing with Hindu theological matters are by default composed in Sanskrit. However, there exists a good amount of religious literature written in regional languages for catering the ordinary masses. As it happens to be, some sects consider certain religious texts written in regional languages to be on par with the Sanskrit canon. Some examples are

1. *Rāmacaritamānasa* & *Hanumānacālisā* of Tulasidāsa in Avadhī language, revered in Rāmānandī sampradāya
2. *Jñāneśvarī Gītā* & *abhang*s of Nāmadeva & Tukārāma in Marāṭhi language, revered by the Varkarī group
3. Saṅkaradeva's *Kīrtanaghoṣa* & rendition of the *Bhāgavata* into Axomiya language, revered by the Ekaśaraṇa group
4. *Caitanyacaritāmṛta* of Kṛṣṇadāsa Kavirāja in Bengali language, revered in the Gauṛīya sampradāya
5. *Nālāyira Divya Prabandha* of the Āḻvārs in Tamil language, revered in Śrīvaiṣnava sampradāya
6. *Tirumurai* of Nāyaṉmārs in Tamil language, revered in Śaivasiddhānta sampradāya.

Now conflict ensures when somebody quotes these texts to refute opinions expressed in the Sanskrit canon, because being composed in a regional language, those texts don't elicit respect from non-native speakers of that language & those not belonging to the *sampradāya*. So what should be the status of these texts in the pan-Hindu community ? Are they to be considered a part of canon, treated as deuterocanonical, or dismissed off as petty religious paeans/panegyrics (for example *Manasāmaṅgala* in Bengali language & the other insignificant *cālisā*s in Hindi language) ?

Comment: Yet the regional scriptures do not seem to contradict basic tenets (vedas /  vedangas) in principle (with regards to tattva , siddhata or aspects of dharma etc.). Their simple exposition of fundamental idea , aid in maintaining the social balance along  the lines , (of tenets) , so, they should be held in  honour . Unity among all bharatiya granthas, is infact admirable, despite all their diversity interms of ethnic , cultural and geographic differences

Comment: @Athrey True. But there exists a bit of favouritism towards Sanskrit in the wider Hindu theological circle. Regional texts are hardly quoted in theological disputes. For example Ramanuja never quoted from the Divyaprabandha in his works inspite of its prestige in his sampradaya. Besides as already stated, regional texts don't command authority outside the sampradaya & linguistic group. You won't find a Gaudiya Vaiṣnava quoting Divyaprabandha while arguing in favour of superiority of a low-caste Vaiṣnava over a non-Vaiṣnava brahmin, although Srivaishnavas also agree to a same theory of sorts.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But I would personally hesitate to quote any regional text, because in my personal opinion, I do not consider them as sacred Hindu text.

Comment: One more text, I guess, is Kathamrita of Sri Ramakrishna. Ramakrishnites consider it important, I guess.