# If only Sanskrit has to be used for prayer/rituals what is the value of works composed in Apabhramsha,Tamil etc.?

Tags: sanskrit

The phenomenally popular Hanuman Chalisa authored by Tulsidas in the Awadhi language

The Divyaprabandam and Tevaram in Tamil

are examples of powerful scriptures that are not in Sanskrit.

Do they have less power than Sanskrit mantras?

Comment: Duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54878/status-of-religious-literature-composed-in-regional-languages

Answer (score 1):

*Bhakti literature , ( compositions by revered saints in various regional languages, do carry the import of Vedas  to its fullest glory). No doubt they should be duly venerated .But they are  composed in a state of ecstasy out of an expression of divine love for supreme, not for the purpose of replacing Veda mantras. It should be understood that they complement Vedas and are recited alongside .The attitude of valuing the bhakti literature must not be grounded on gauging how powerful it is ?or by a comparison of it with Vedas or whatsoever.*

> There is a mantra to cure scorpion sting. Its meaning is not revealed. Its
> potency is in its sound. Certain sounds have certain powers associated
> with them. It is sometimes asked: Why should the sraddha mantras be in
> Sanskrit? May they not be in English or Tamil? Those who raise these
> questions do not realise that it is the sound that matters here, not the
> language as such. If the teeth of a sorcerer were knocked off, his
> witchcraft [magic] would have no effect. Why? Because the man would
> not be able to recite this spell properly.
> Enunciation of the mantras is most important to the Vedas. What do we
> do about it? Siksa is the science that deals with the character of Vedic
> syllables it determines their true nature. The science of the sounds of
> human speech is called phonetics and it is more important to the Vedic
> language than to any other tongue. The reason is that even if there is slight change in how you vocalise a syllable the efficacy of the mantra will
> be affected. [The result sometimes will be contrary to what is intended].
> It is because of the importance of Vedic phonetics that Siksa has been
> placed first among the six Angas. Sanskrit fully represents the Supreme Being manifested as the Sabda-brahman.
> The sound of the Vedas must pervade everywhere, must fill all space. The
> truths enshrined in them must be spread far and wide and the **rituals
> enjoined on us by them must be made to flourish. Sufficient it would be if
> the Vedic dharma remains vigorous and is maintained atleast in our land.**
> If a man's heart is stout he will survive even if all other parts of his body
> are afflicted. In the same way, if the Vedas flourish in this land all nations
> will prosper and live in peace and happiness. This is the prayer of the
> Vedic dharma.
> *"Lookah samastah sukhnio bhavantu.”*
> .
> Vedas are also called
> "Sruti", which means "that which is heard", that is to say not be learned
> from any written text. Since listening to the Vedas as they were chanted
> and then memorizing them was the practice, preserving the Vedic
> tradition came to be full-time vocation.
> .
> It is only in Sanskrit that the sound of the word itself
> signifies its meaning. So that must be the root form of the word. Hence
> languages like English, French, Latin, etc, must have been derived from
> Sanskrit. *Western philologists do not accept Sanskrit as the original
> language, the mother of all Indo-European tongues.*
> .
> In speaking about the Vedas I stated that the sound of a word was more
> important that its meaning. That reminds me. In the Vedic language
> called "Chandas" and Sanskrit which is based on it, so there are words the
> very sound of which denotes their meaning
> .
> Some do not seem to attach any special significance to the
> fact that the Vedas are in Sanskrit. They think that these sacred texts
> could be known through translations..
> **Pujya Sri Chandrasekhara Saraswati Swami , Hindu dhama, The universal way of life**

> Saivas
> describe Isvara thus:
> **Vedamodarangamayinanai
> Vedanathan, Vedagitan, aranan kan**
> Similarly, the Vaisnava texts proclaim, **Vedam Tamizh seytaMaran
> Sathakopan**. "If we pay close attention to their utterances, we will
> discover that the Vedas are the prime scripture of both sects. The
> Tevaram and the Nalayaira-Divyaprabandham are of the utmost
> importance to them (to the Saivas and Vaisnavas respectively); but the
> Vedas are the basis of both. The great saint-poets who composed the
> Saiva and Vaisnava hymns sing the glories of the Vedas throughout.
> Whenever they describe a temple, they go into raptures, saying, "Here
> the air is filled with the sound of the Vedas and pervaded with the smoke
> of the sacrificial fire. Here the six Angas of the Vedas flourish. " In thesongs of these hymnodists veneration of the Vedas finds as much place as
> devotion to the Lord.
> The Vedas reveal the One Truth to us in the form of many deities. The
> worship of each of these divine beings is like a ghat on the river called the
> Vedas. Sekkizhar says the same thing: **Veda neri tazhaittonga mihu
> Saivatturai vilanga**
> Apart from Saivism and Vaisnavism, there are a number of sectarian
> systems like Saktam, Ganapatyam, Kaumaram, and Sauram (worship of
> Sakti, Ganapati, Kumara or Subrahmanya and the Sun God). The
> adoration of these deities is founded in the Vedas, according to the Texts
> relating to them: "Our deity is extolled in the Vedas, " each system
> contains such a declaration
> **Pujya Sri Chandrasekhara Saraswati Swami , Hindu dhama, The universal way of life**